# Google Fit Delete dataSource?

Tags: rest, google-api, datasource, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I've created an application which creates a weight data source.  Unfortunately, I had a typo in my application such that the field name was incorrectly typed as "kg" instead of "weight":

```
  {
   "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.weight:myappwhatever",
   "name": "Weight Feed",
   "type": "raw",
   "dataType": {
    "name": "com.google.weight",
    "field": [
     {
      "name": "kg",
      "format": "floatPoint"
     }
    ]
   }
```

While the REST API has an update method, it does not support changing the fields, and unfortunately the REST API does not have a delete method.

The impact of this problem is that on the Android the logs indicate:

```
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809): FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809): Process: com.google.process.location, PID: 8809
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809): com.google.android.gms.fitness.l.ab: Conflicting data types!  New: DataType{com.google.weight[kg(f)]}, existing: DataType{com.google.weight[weight(f)]}
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809):  at com.google.android.gms.fitness.l.af.b(SourceFile:180)
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809):  at com.google.android.gms.fitness.l.af.d(SourceFile:594)
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809):  at com.google.android.gms.fitness.l.af.d(SourceFile:552)
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809):  at com.google.android.gms.fitness.l.af.b(SourceFile:2740)
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809):  at com.google.android.gms.fitness.sync.b.a(SourceFile:244)
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809):  at com.google.android.gms.fitness.sync.c.onPerformSync(SourceFile:113)
02-24 20:50:48.527 E/AndroidRuntime(8809):  at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
```

Is there another way to update the field or to delete the data source?

Answer (score 0):

For those in the future:
There is currently no fix for this, but one is being worked on.

[Google+ Link](https://plus.google.com/+EricYTheriault/posts/FABasGiMWbF)

From the link:

> Thanks for the feedback and bug report!
>
> There is currently no way to fix this, but it may be possible for us to correct it with a server-side fix, which usually has a faster turnaround time than a client side one (1-2 weeks).
>
> I'll update this thread as soon as I get an update, or you can follow along in our bug tracker.

Public issue tracker [[here]](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/1naNyQJq3LwyIYhLoLL0V8hBJCrrBwhge9qEOu47Pwu4/edit?usp=sharing) lists fix ETA as 1st April 2015.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ruffp  I disagree here.  OP asked 'Is there a way" and Lucas answered 'No'.  The link just adds peripheral info about a possible future change.

Comment: Ok but what happens if the Google+ page disappear? it would be nicer to put a citation of the Google answer here...

Comment: @ruffp I edited the response to include the info from G+ as well as the link to the public issue tracker.